# Cakephp ignores my locale files

Tags: cakephp, locale, cakephp-3.0

I always have to translate my applications to italian, and I did it several times but I can't make it work with CakePHP 3.0. This is what I did:

I extracted a .pot file through console's cake i18n. 
Uploaded it to poeditor and edited all of my strings
Downloaded it to src/Locale/it/default.po as the manual (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) says
Checked that config/bootstrap had the right language set:

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'it_IT');
```

As it didn't work, I tried with dumb things like renaming my folder to src/Locale/it_IT/default.po, src/Locale/ita/default.po, wrapped my .po file inside a LC_MESSAGES like it was with CakePHP 2.x... still no results.

Debug is set to true, so there should be no caching...

I know this is probably a dumb question, but i've past hours on this and still I can't get it working... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry I got the problem and I'm really ashamed of that... The file was in the right position (src/Locale/it/default.po) and everything was set fine, but it didn't have read permissions for apache. Sorry!

Edit: This is an old question but I've had this same issue with a new CakePHP 4 project. Turns out that in this case Cake needs read and write permission in order to actually use those files. I hope this helps.

Comment: Good thing you figured it though. These types of 'errors' are always evil.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have spent hours. why there are no message at all

Comment: Man, thanks taking time to go back here and posting your solution (very simple and useful). I was having this problem for two days and spent several hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same. Those files should be under tmp or sth

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck for an hour, it would have been more without this post.

Answer (score 3):

Try to go to your server and from the folder `app/tmp/cache/view` , `app/tmp/cache/model` and `app/tmp/cache/persistant` delete the files you see in there. This is the cache your app is using.

Comment: this is cakephp 3 op is asking about

Comment: This actually worked for me in CakePHP3. Although I knew it was a caching problem and I did not know where it was being cached.